# Does the parameter of a mocked resource in a unit test matter?

Tags: c#, api, unit-testing, mocking

My question relates to when we're mocking external resources (in my case, they are an external API and a Database).

Let's say I expect a result of a request to be of a certain object, based on an input I provide (an ID, for example).
As I'm testing, I tend to use `It.IsAny<int>`, instead of writing a real ID because I see it as unnecessary since it is a mocked object and my main concern is what is returned from the method.

**Method of Service.cs**

```
public async IActionResult CreateObject(Guid? objectID){
   var response = await myApi.GetObjectFromApi(objectID);
   
   if(!response.IsSuccessStatusCode){
      throw new HttpResponseException(response.StatusCode);
   }
   return Ok(response);
}
```

**Test**

```
[Test]
public void CreateObject_ReturnsSuccess(){
   // mocked myApi dependency
   _myApiMock
         .Setup(x=>x.GetObjectFromApi(It.IsAny<Guid>())
         .Returns(new HttpResponseMessage(){ StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK }

   var response = CreateObject(Guid.Parse("81a130d2-502f-4cf1-a376-63edeb000e9f"));

   Assert.That(response.StatusCode, Is.Equal(HttpStatusCode.OK));
}
```

My question is:
Since I'm mocking the API dependency, is there any point in using actual Guid values other than for readability? (line -> ***`.Setup(x=>x.GetObjectFromApi(It.IsAny<Guid>())`***)

Comment: If you never check what the code you're testing called the collaborator with, you leave yourself open to finding out later on it wasn't what you expected. Maybe it wasn't the one you passed in?

Comment: I understand what you mean. Maybe I wasn't very clear. In this case, I just want to test the logic of the service method (the if statement). That's why I mocked the API resource. So, since I can mock it and make sure that the response is either always success or bad request or anything else, does it matter if I write down a real Guid or if I just write It.IsAny<Guid>()?

Comment: No it does not matter. If you were to use `It.Is<Guid>` you could verify that your dependent function is passing in an expected value to the mocked function. It allows you to verify exactly what guid is being passed if there were some intermediate operations on it.  If you don't care, or you're controlling the value in the test  `It.IsAny<Guid>` will just verify the type passed to the mock function. Side note, Is that test even working though? Have you injected your mock api somewhere?

Comment: Thank you for clarifying it for me! @StiyAle This is not a real test even though it is based on something that I wrote for a program I'm developing. It was a way to better ilustrate my confusion. Anyways, thank you very much for clarifying it for me!

Comment: It all depends on what you will assert. There might be cases in which you want to check an ID against another object that was retrieved, and things in which the ID is needed to verify the method is really passing. There is no you never need it or you always need it.

Comment: In my case, I just wanted to verify if against the type of response that could come from the API (Bad request, success, etc). That's why it was always very confusing for me, but now I understand

Comment: Really what matters is what's communicated about your expectations for the code you're testing. To me, `It.IsAny<Guid>()` suggests _"we can't control this exactly"_ - maybe the code under test is creating its own GUID, which will be different each time. But in this case you're passing it in, so if you extract `Guid.Parse("81a130d2-502f-4cf1-a376-63edeb000e9f")` to the start of the test and use that it's clear that you expect the same GUID to be passed through. If it's _not_, you'll find out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer given by  @Jonrsharpe in the comments helped me understanding the problem and implementing the solution for my use case.

"Really what matters is what's communicated about your expectations for the code you're testing. To me, `It.IsAny<Guid>()` suggests "we can't control this exactly" - maybe the code under test is creating its own GUID, which will be different each time. But in this case you're passing it in, so if you extract `Guid.Parse("81a130d2-502f-4cf1-a376-63edeb000e9f")` to the start of the test and use that it's clear that you expect the same GUID to be passed through. If it's not, you'll find out." - Jonrsharpe